# Gelfand's Formula. $r(T)=\lim_{n \to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\|T^{n}\|}$

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

Can you indicate me a material where I cand find the proof of Gelfand's Formula. I heard that there is a proof with polynomials.

> Gelfand's Formula :
>
> If $T \in B(X)$ then: $$r(T)=\lim_{n \to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\|T^{n}\|}$$

thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know of any proof using just polynomials. All the proofs I have seen involve complex analysis to a certain extent, either Laurent series expansions, Liouville's theorem, or Hadamard's Theorem.

I am pretty sure that most books on functional analysis which cover Banach spaces and/or Banach algebras will contain a proof, for example:

G. F. Simmons - [Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Topology-Modern-Analysis-Simmons/dp/1575242389) - page 312 in my (old) edition.

Riesz and Nagy - [Functional Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Analysis-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486662896) - section 149 (page 425 in my Dover edition).